# How to make a readonly select dropdown?

Tags: php, zend-framework, drop-down-menu, readonly

I am trying following to make a dropdown readonly:

```
$element = $this->CreateElement('select', 'type');
$element->addMultiOptions( $Types );
$element->setRequired(true);
$element->setAttrib('readonly',true);
$element->setLabel('Type');
$elements[] = $element;
```

A dropdown is shown but I am able to select other values.

How to make a dropdown readonly ?

Thanks

Comment: @Xeon06: A dropdown that have multiple items but user can't change it manually. But it should post the current item on form submission.

Comment: Some users have access to only one type in dropdown items. So therefore they can't change the selected item. It will be populated automatically on form load. On the other hand some users have access to all types in dropdown. So they are free to change the value and submit the form.

Comment: Why not just put one type in the dropdown if the user only has access to one and all the types if they have access to all of them? That makes more sense and consistency IMO.

Comment: Yes. It is also a good option. But is there no such readonly thing with html dropdown ?

Comment: No, because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the read only attribute. You could avoid outputting a dropdown at all if it is not the best element to use in your particular case.

```
$element->setAttrib('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: I need to post the current selected value but dont need to change the selected value.

Comment: Problem is that some users have access to only one type and some users have access to all types in dropdown items..

Comment: On the element you select, `$element->setAttrib('selected','selected');`

Comment: What does `element->setAttrib('selected','selected');` do ?

Comment: It sets which option is selected.

Comment: I have dropdown with multiple items but user have right to post only one populated value. So user should not have access to change the select item in dropdown. Therefore I asked to make it readonly. You suggested to disable the dropdown but it will not post the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to only have one value selected, you could always disable it. Using your current framework, you might do something like:

```
$element->setAttrib('disabled', true);
```